# Automatically generate chatroom when onclick button

Tags: django, django-models, web-chat, chatroom

I wanna make a chat app that when clients click on the button, they will connect and chat with the admin. Each admin has a button only and he can chat with many clients. Each client can chat with many admin too. 1 chatroom has only 2 users (admin+client).
My solution is when clients click the button, it will generate a chatroom and add user_id of admin and client into its.
But now I'm struggling to find way to automatically generate a chatroom with random id or name.
Hope you guys can help me <3

Comment: What have you done/tried already and what did you encounter?

Comment: I've just done with creating a basic chat app that onclick button redirect to generate a room manually. Two users need to proactively type the same room's name to enter a same room.

Comment: I think i need to use signal for auto generating room, right?

Comment: I don't know, because I never built something similar. I asked you because you could maybe update your opening post, add tags and code so others find this based on relevance and might help you out. You do have to show the effort though.

Comment: After searching for hours, I think my chat app is similar to private chat. So now I'm researching django private chat to find out something helpful. Sorry, I can't upload my code because this is one of my final project :( Anyway, thank you very much, I appreciate your advice <3